# Front-end (ReactJS) to Backend(NodeJS) Authentication

Tags: reactjs

New to React and quite confused...trying to access protected Node routes from React...how do I go about setting this authorization header upon login/registration? I have login / registration working fine for React...just kinda stuck here...

Of course I can set the header in Postman and it works...well in straight Node..

```
const JwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader("authorization"),
  secretOrKey: secret
};

const jwtAuth = new JwtStrategy(JwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
  User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, false);
    }
    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), you can add the `Authorization` header to your requests like this:

```
axios({ method: 'get', url: '/protected_route', headers: { Authorization: token } });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks...I did that in a tutorial and was trying to work around it. But you are correct. I went back over a tuts project and saw it....Thanks!

Comment: One more thing...that works. When I login the page goes to the profile page but I have to refresh the page to get the values...I know this is simple but I am missing something...

Comment: It would be nice if you could also attach the frontend code in your question

Comment: The axios method fixed it